# Can we merge [icao-recommendations] into [icao-sarps] and make it a synonym?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

This question is related to discussion from the [ICAO Standards and Recommended Practices](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3047/755) question from about a month ago. A bit before that question, the [icao-sarps](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/icao-sarps) tag was created, in addition to the [icao-recommendations](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/icao-recommendations) tag that already existed. As was mentioned in that meta post and its comments and answers, SARPs is indeed the correct name, but many people will likely not be familiar with it.

Since these tags seem to be redundant, I recommend retagging all of the questions with [icao-recommendations](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/icao-recommendations) to [icao-sarps](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/icao-sarps) and making [icao-recommendations](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/icao-recommendations) be a synonym for [icao-sarps](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/icao-sarps). This way, newcomers who aren't familiar with the SARPs terminology can easily find the right tag and we won't have two redundant tags floating around.

Can we make this happen?

Comment: I'm not sure if the primary tag should be [tag:icao-sarps], particularly given [tag:icao-recommendations] has more questions (the preferred tag by volume of usage, if not by technical accuracy).

Comment: @voretaq7 I think a lot of that difference has to do with the tag ages, though. [tag:icao-recommendations] is over 2 years old, while [tag:icao-sarps] is only a bit under a couple of months old. At any rate, whichever is preferred, I think they're redundant and should be synonyms.

Comment: @voretaq7 I've added an answer that explains a bit more why I prefer [tag:icao-sarps] over [tag:icao-recommendations], but I'm open to either (or something else.) The main thing is just that we don't need redundant tags.

Comment: Now that we're at it, we should get rid 'easa-regulations' and replace it with 'eu-regulations' :)

Comment: @J.Hougaard I'm not sure if you're just joking or not, but if you do want to propose that, I'd recommend a new meta post where it can be discussed separately. In general, though, we've kept the tag names based on the name of the agency that promulgates the regulations rather than the place (e.g. faa-regulations, not usa-regulations.)

Comment: EU is the agency that promultages the regulations. EASA are simply advising them

Comment: good news: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57309431#57309431 ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit 3/11/21 : This has now been implemented.

---

There are two primary reasons why I think [icao-sarps](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/icao-sarps) should be the preferred tag and [icao-recommendations](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/icao-recommendations) should be a synonym to it, rather than the other way around:

- The term 'SARPs' is more precise, as this is the term that ICAO itself uses.
- The tag name [icao-recommendations](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/icao-recommendations) becomes a bit ambiguous in light of ICAO "Recommended Procedures" having a defined meaning that is only a subset of what the tag is used for.

It's true that all ICAO SARPs are effectively recommendations for policy and not actual enforced policy, so the name 'recommendations' is not inaccurate per se, but it seems like having the tag name be [icao-recommendations](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/icao-recommendations) could make it ambiguous whether the tag should be used for any question about ICAO Standards or Recommended Procedures or only those specifically about ICAO Recommended Procedures.

I suppose we could make the preferred tag name be [icao-standards-and-recommendations](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/icao-standards-and-recommendations) to prevent this ambiguity while also avoiding the use of a not-terribly-common acronym, but that seems like a really long tag name. I wouldn't be opposed to it if that's what others prefer, though.

As Voretaq7 mentioned in a comment on the question, there are more questions currently tagged as [icao-recommendations](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/icao-recommendations) (25) vs. [icao-sarps](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/icao-sarps) (5), but I'd guess that discrepancy probably has more to do with the former being much older than the latter (over 2 years vs. 2 months.)

Comment: I created the [tag:icao-sarps] exactly for this reason. My effort to retag all recommendations got stuck.

Comment: I think that your long suggestion is too long to be a tag, and I agree that the length of time that the tags have been around is a big factor in the difference in the number of questions that each has.  I'm pretty sure that I was the original one who use the icao-recommendations and it was partly due to not being aware of the sarps term, and partly wanting to be clear that ICAO recommendations are not the "rules" that many people view them as.  Personally, I agree with your suggestion.

Comment: Is there an SE "policy" in regards to creating tags prior to there being any questions so associated? i.e. Might we also create an [tag:icao-standards] tag as a syn to [tag:icao-sarps]?

Comment: @CGCampbell I would assume that can be done with synonyms, since they technically don't ever have questions associated with them anyway. I could be wrong, though.

Answer (score 1):

I was composing the same request and came here by way of "similar questions".

@reirab's answer offers alternatives, so perhaps that's why no action was taken in the past 3 years and 2 months.

Here's my opinion:

- [icao-sarps](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/icao-sarps) as the master tag

  - [icao-recommendations](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/icao-recommendations) to become a synonym
  - [icao-standards](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/icao-standards) to be created and made a synonym

The proper name [icao-recommended-practices] is not really needed as while typing "recommen--" the proper suggestion [icao-sarps] will appear.